# Renaming directories using find and sed replacements

Tags: macos, sed, find

I'm trying to rename some directories with find and sed the but switching the directory name around based.

example directory name:

```
rabbit_stand_a_e
rabbit_stand_a_ne
```

I want these changing to:

```
rabbit_a_stand_e
rabbit_a_stand_ne
```

so I wanted to essentially split by _ and switch $2 and $3 around

I've tried a few things, but can't get anything to work, here's where I'm at right now.

```
find . -type d -execdir mv {} `echo {} | sed -E 's/rabbit_([a-z]+)_([abc])_/rabbit_\2_\1_/'` \;
```

this errors with

```
mv: cannot move ‘rabbit_stand_a_e’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘rabbit_stand_a_e/rabbit_stand_a_e’
```

Comment: and, learn to debug problems like this by selecting 1 representative filename, and rather than use `find`, use `echo rabbit_stand_a_e | sed -E 's/....//'` to see where your problem is. In  this case you have tor realize that `mv` requires and source and a target param. Anyway ... good luck!

Comment: Hmm, I thought I was giving two, `mv {} \`echo.....` {} being the current

Comment: My sed works fine on it's own in isolation like you suggest `echo rabbit_stand_a_w | sed -E 's/rabbit_([a-z]+)_([abc])_/rabbit_\2_\1_/'` so i must be miss using -exec or mv

Comment: used a for loop and all is working `for i in \`find . -type d\`; do mv $i \`echo $i | sed -E 's/rabbit_([a-z]+)_([abc])_/rabbit_\2_\1_/'\`; done`

Comment: You could make use of `rename` command. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from when `find` does substitution for the `{}` argument vs when your shell runs the subshell (the part of the command enclosed in backticks).

All subshells are evaluated *before* the given command is run. This means you end up running your `echo {} | sed ...'` command *before* the `{}` gets substituted with a filename, which means you're literally echoing the string `"{}"` and piping it into `sed`. Since your `sed` pattern doesn't match `"{}"`, it just returns `{}` unchanged, leaving you with this:

```
find . -type d -execdir mv {} {}
```

Now when `find` runs it replaces both occurrences of `{}` with the given directory name, hence your error message about trying to move the directory into itself.

The easiest way to fix this is probably to interpret the whole command with `bash -c` and pass in the argument `{}` to bash:

```
find . -type d -execdir bash -c 'mv $1 `echo $1 | sed -E "s/rabbit_([a-z]+)_([abc])_/rabbit_\2_\1_/"`' -- {} \;
```

I think there should be a straightforward way to do this with `xargs`, but it's not immediately obvious to me at the moment. If I think of it later I'll update my answer (or if anyone else wants to chime in with a comment that'd be appreciated).

---

Related reading: [Subshell arguments in -exec parameter for find(1)](https://superuser.com/questions/410321/subshell-arguments-in-exec-parameter-for-find1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, perfect. I was able to get the behaviour I needed with a for loop aswell